# electron webview get scrambled in a rare case

Tags: google-chrome, electron

I got a bug report in my electron app. It looks like below~
We can't find a way to reproduce this.
I believe it's some kind of visual memory corruption, but I don't know how it happens...

[image]

Comment: Very strange indeed, It's going to be difficult because you can't reproduce it but I'd see if the same thing happens on somebody else's computer.

Comment: I haven't seen it that bad but I see something like it with Visual Studio Code all the time – less with my own `Electron` apps. No help but I think I recall seeing a mention of this visual glitch at the `Electron` github site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in Apple's latest 16' MacBook pro. Likely to happen when the system is recovered from sleep mode.

It's also happening in chrome/chromium.

Here is the issue track link:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068170